# Delete an entry from a collection in Clojure

Tags: collections, syntax, clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I'm wondering how I remove an element from a collection.

Say I have:

```
(def example ["a" "b" "c"])
```

I want to be able to remove say "b" and when I call

```
(println example)
```

and have it return a collection with only "a" and "c"

I know using `(remove (partial = "b") example)`
will return what I want but then how do i update the example variable with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `filter` instead

Comment: AFAIK the Clojure style to do things is using immutable data structures. Therefore, `example` should remain as it is forever. You should create new collections, e.g. using filter as already pointed.

Answer (score 1):

```
(filter (fn [x] (not (= x "b"))) example)
```

Will get you `'("a" "c")`. Couple of points:

1. You shouldn't be thinking in terms of mutation. The whole point of using functional programming in general and clojure with it's persistent data structures in particular is to avoid the problems associated with mutability.
2. If you *do* really, really need something to be mutable you can use atoms, but if you're not *sure* you need it to be mutable, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you really need mutation in the first place. Clojure is designed around working with immutable data - there's a chance that what you ultimately want to do can be achieved without changing values in place.

If you need mutable data, you can create an atom for that - changing a car's value is generally a bad practice.

```
(def example (atom ["a" "b" "c"]))

(println @example) ;; ["a" "b" "c"]

(swap! example #(remove (partial = "b") %))

(println @example) ;; ["a" "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Clojure's default data structures are immutable. Hence you cannot change a vector in place, but you can create a new one with the desired elements.

In a function context, this is how you could use remove:

```
(defn my-func [col]
  (let [without-b (remove #(= "b" %) col)]
     (println without-b)
     ; do something else w/ without-b
  ))
...
 => (my-func ["a" "b" "c"])
 (a c)
```

This is the idiomatic Clojure way to work with collections, i.e., you create a new collection from an old one. This doesn't have "significant" memory or performance implications, as the data structures are implemented on a tree-based data structure, Tries, you can learn more about this here:
https://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1